# Laptop AC adapter stopped charging after changing the OS

Tags: windows-7, ac-adapter

I am facing a problem with my **HP compaq 6710b**

I have a 90 watt battery adapter which was working fine(i have tested it in other laptops too) when I had Windows XP Professional installed in my Laptop. When I installed Windows 7 Ultimate (32 bit) I am facing the following problems:

- My laptop is **NOT charging with this AC Adapter** (90 watt). Other chargers like 60 watt & 95 watt charger are charging my laptop well.
- **Laptop FAN is making so much noise.**

**How exactly how i know the charger is not charging the laptop?**

I have remove my  battery and plugged in my (90 watt)charger then i found my system is not getting power on & even no any Power light is glowing. And also if i insert other charger (like 95 watt & 60 watt Hp charger) then i can see the power on light glowing.

Here are more details about my laptop:

**OS Name** Microsoft Windows 7 Ultimate (32 bit) Version 6.1.7600 Build 7600
**System Manufacturer** Hewlett-Packard
**System Model** HP Compaq 6710b (GF929AW#ABA)
**System Type** X86-based PC
**Processor** Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU T7500 @ 2.20GHz, 2200 Mhz, 2 Core(s), 2 Logical Processor(s)
**BIOS Version/Date** Hewlett-Packard 68DDU Ver. F.20, 12/1/2011 SMBIOS Version 2.4
**Hardware Abstraction Layer Version** "6.1.7600.16385"
**Windows Directory** C:\Windows
**System Directory** C:\Windows\system32
**Boot Device** \Device\HarddiskVolume1
**Locale** United States
**Installed Physical Memory (RAM)** 2.00 GB
**Total Physical Memory** 1.99 GB
**Available Physical Memory** 215 MB
**Total Virtual Memory** 3.98 GB
**Available Virtual Memory** 1.07 GB
**Page File Space** 1.99 GB
**Page File** C:\pagefile.sys

---

### Update:

I checked the charger is working fine. Even my 90 watt charger i went and checked with other laptop its charging very perfectly.
And another thing what i tested is 
If i charge my laptop with AC-adapter 60watt or with 95 watt then its charging nicely but why i am facing this problem with my original charger i.e 90 watt
And even i installed the hp bios drivers from this link http://tinyurl.com/prv3ah3  . but also the same problem

Comment: why i am not receiving any answer for my above question?  Do i need to update my question once again? please help me

Comment: Everyone answers questions for free. This is not a pay-for- help site. There is reasonable expectation the person posting a question has attempted to resolve things before posting the question. This is outlined in the [help] section. Please [edit] your question with some details of what you have tried and/or researched. The request for help "as soon as possible because my works are stopped", doesn't typically help. It makes it seem as though you expect others to do the work for you.

Comment: You probably need to get a driver from HP for this laptop.  Try HP technical support.

Comment: @CharlieRB i updated

Comment: @Sundara - Your question requires more then 20 minutes to solve. Have you cleaned the insides of your laptop out recently. Fan noise indicates your laptop is having problems cooling itself.  How exactly do you know the charger is not charging the laptop?  Update your question, be specific, do not post a comment to answer these questions.

Comment: @KevinPanko And even i installed the hp bios drivers from this link http://tinyurl.com/prv3ah3 . but also the same problem

Comment: Maybe this update will help.  http://h20565.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.PAGE/public/psi/swdDetails/?sp4ts.oid=3356622&spf_p.tpst=swdMain&spf_p.prp_swdMain=wsrp-navigationalState%3Didx%253D%257CswItem%253Dob_77187_1%257CswEnvOID%253D4055%257CitemLocale%253D%257CswLang%253D%257Cmode%253D%257Caction%253DdriverDocument&javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken

Comment: @Ramhound  I have updated my question.  **How i know its not charging?** I have remove my  battery and plugged in my (90 watt)charger then i found my system is not getting power on no any Power light glowing. And also if i insert other charger (like 95 watt & 60 watt Hp charger) then i can see the power on.

Comment: @KevinPanko i downloaded and clicked on "repair" button and restarted my Laptop and kept 90watt charger for testing but still i can see the same issue

Comment: @CharlieRB Is this http://jeffreypalermo.com/blog/plugged-in-not-charging-windows-7-solution/ will help me ? what do you think?

Comment: I don't know if it will work. Did you try it?

Comment: @CharlieRB no because i could not understand the point number 6. i.e `Under the Batteries category, right-click all of the Microsoft ACPI Compliant Control Method Battery listings, and select Uninstall (it’s ok if you only have 1).`

Comment: @CharlieRB why my question is voted down? Its very useful question i think. I have answered it below. May be it will help someone ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution of my above question

**For battery problem:**

- Actually for me there was no problem with battery but it was problem with my ac adapter. So Changed the new AC adapter

**For Noise problem:**

- I cleaned the vent of my Laptop Fan and removed dust from the motherboard

Now my problem has been solved. I got these answer from HP support team...

Answer (score 1):

An operating system wouldn't have anything to do with your system being charged by your adapter. Based off of your statement that other adapters charge your system fine, and that particular 90w adapter (which I'm also assuming is the one that came with your laptop) is not, and including that you upgraded your OS from XP (translation: old equipment), I'd venture to say that your power adapter is probably not working properly. Either hook up a multimeter to see what power is actually coming out of it, or try plugging it into another system (since you said you had other power adapters, I am assuming you also have the devices that use those adapters) and see if it charges those.

As a disclaimer, you mentioned a 60w power adapter, and I'd recommend against plugging a 90w power adapter into a device that only requires 60w, as doing so could fry some circuitry.

Comment: If the charger was working before the OS upgrade, then it's probably working now.

Comment: @KevinPanko I checked the charger is working fine. Even my 90 watt charger i went and checked with other laptop its charging very perfectly. And another thing what i tested is If i charge my laptop with AC-adapter 60watt or with 95 watt then its charging nicely but why i am facing this problem with my original charger i.e 90 watt

Comment: @Sacto_Smithers assuming both power adapters are the same voltage and polarity, the higher-wattage power adapter will not fry the laptop because the laptop will only draw what it needs. Many laptops are designed to work with both a higher-capacity and lower-capacity charger, and will charge faster when connected to the higher-capacity power adapter.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the ACPI driver is messed up. I have experienced this problem a few times on my trusty Dell Latitude E6410. This procedure gets things going

1. Disconnect the AC from the laptop
2. Shutdown the computer
3. Remove battery
4. Re-connect the AC
5. Startup the computer
6. Go to Control Panel and open Device Manager
7. Expand the Batteries category and right-click all of the Microsoft ACPI Compliant Control Method Battery listings, and select Uninstall.
8. Shutdown the computer
9. Disconnect the AC from the laptop and unplug the connection from the wall socket.
10. Re-insert the battery
11. Re-connect the AC
12. Startup the computer

Comment: Still the same problem . i already tried this http://jeffreypalermo.com/blog/plugged-in-not-charging-windows-7-solution/     . please read my question once again

Comment: http://superuser.com/a/691974/280790